# The axes labels do not align with the matrix when using matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used the following code to create the attached plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(50)
fig.set_figwidth(50)
ax.matshow(power_final_for_plotting, cmap='GnBu', origin='upper')
ax.set_xticks(time_periods)
ax.set_xticklabels(time_periods)
ax.set_yticks(sig_wave_height)
ax.set_yticklabels(sig_wave_height)
for i in range(len(time_periods)):
    for j in range(len(amplitude)):
        c = round(power_final_for_plotting[j, i],3)
        ax.text(i, j, str(c), va='center', ha='center', size=27)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here time_period and sig_wave_height are lists of integers. The axis labels do not align properly in this case (Check the top right of the image to see the labels as they are). How can I fix this? The labels are really small in this case:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current scale definition, for example, gives the necessary amount of x-axis as a numerical value, but the scale name is displayed up to 15 because it is a numerical value. We need 30 tick points and tick names for each column. Since no data is provided, I have created sample data as appropriate. Also, the small font of the scale is due to the size of 50 inches.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

power_final_for_plotting = np.random.rand(450).reshape(15,30)
time_periods = np.arange(0,15,0.5)
sig_wave_height = np.arange(0.5,8.0,0.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(6)
fig.set_figwidth(12)
ax.matshow(power_final_for_plotting, cmap='GnBu', origin='upper')
ax.set_xticks(range(len(time_periods)))
ax.set_xticklabels([str(x) for x in time_periods])
ax.set_yticks(range(len(sig_wave_height)))
ax.set_yticklabels([str(x) for x in sig_wave_height])
for i in range(len(time_periods)):
    for j in range(len(sig_wave_height)):
        c = round(power_final_for_plotting[j, i],3)
        ax.text(i, j, str(c), va='center', ha='center', size=9)
plt.tight_layout()
#print(ax.get_xticklabels())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.